# how to moderate comments from social plugin facebook?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I've just added this snippet to my wordpress blog...

```
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=145875562182317";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

With the code below on my single.php template.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-num-posts="10" data-width="642"></div>
```

Source taken from facebook developers site...
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

This has added a sweet facebook comments box onto my blog posts. But I need to moderate the comments some how?

So I've read the documentation and it says add this meta into your head with my user ID.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="6468594984"/>
```

This seemed to work, only if I went to that post when I was logged in as facebook user 6468594984 - and I could see a moderator view button on the comments box. So this worked.

How ever this is slightly impractical.. so I went to the next level.

I created a facebook app with the correct site URL on the website tab ending with... /

Changed my previous meta for this...

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="766484684648"/>
```

and I presumed by going to...

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

...that I could now moderate all the comments for my wordpress site by viewing app 766484684648.

But no comments are appearing on app id 766484684648 within the tools comments site.

Can any one help enlighten me on where I've gone wrong or where I need to fix.

Thanks hugely!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you changed your meta tag, did you run your URL through the URL Linter? Perhaps Facebook just had not detected the change you made to the meta tag, due to caching.

Try pasting the URL you use for the comments module into http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and verify that there are no errors, and that the app id is coming through.